# Retrieve data from the database using Eloquent between two dates

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble retrieving data from the database using Eloquent. I am trying to retrieve all data between two dates (`created_at` field).

I've done this:

```
 public function search(Request $request){
        $start_date  = $request->get('start_date');
        $end_date = $request->get('end_date');

        $getinfo =  DB::table('media')
            ->join('content_forms', 'media.id', "=", 'content_forms.media_id')
            ->whereBetween('Date_Occured',[$start_date, $end_date])
            ->get();
        dd($getinfo);
    }
```

Comment: value of start_date and end_date are in dd_mm_YYYY format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to select between dates of the media table for example, then fully qualify the field e.g.

```
$getinfo =  DB::table('media')
            ->join('content_forms', 'media.id', "=", 'content_forms.media_id')
            ->whereBetween('media.created_at', [$start_date, $end_date]);
            ->get();
```

Also make sure the dates passed in the request are in a correct *YYYY-mm-dd* format

Comment: thanks but if the format of the created_at column are in dd_mm_yyyy? is it appropiate to use where between?

Comment: when I dd i gotCollection {#310 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => {#311 ▼
      +"id": 41
      +"media_name": "THE CITIZEN"
      +"created_at": "2018-01-02 11:50:36"
      +"updated_at": "2018-01-02 11:50:36"
      +"user_id": 25
      +"media_id": 7
      +"Content_title": "TRA mbeya"
      +"Content_Description": "      tito                              "
      +"Date_Occured": "02-01-2018"
      +"Page_Number": "8"
      +"image": null
      +"Status": "Approved"
      +"retry": "retry"
    } while start date is 01/02/2018 and end date 02/02/2018

Comment: You need to format the date like **2018-02-01 00:00:00** and **2018-02-02 00:00:00**

Comment: Thanks its fine now